# Keyboard Avoiding View problem in flatlist in inputtext field

Tags: ios, react-native, textinput, flatlist

I am unable to achieve keyboard avoiding functionality in flat list on IOS anyone have a solution for this ?

I am trying to apply keyboard avoiding view into the Flat-List Input Field but its not working properly in IOS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.